# XOR linked list implementation

Tags: c, linked-list, interview-questions

I am trying to resolve below question in order to prepare for an interview xD

> An XOR linked list is a more memory efficient doubly linked list.
> Instead of each node holding next and prev fields, it holds a field
> named both, which is an XOR of the next node and the previous node.
> Implement an XOR linked list; it has an add(element) which adds the
> element to the end, and a get(index) which returns the node at
> index.

Please suggest how this implementation can be improved. Thank you in prior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
    long both;
    
} StNode; 
typedef StNode *pStNode;

pStNode add(pStNode lastNode, int value)
{
    pStNode newNode = (StNode *) malloc(sizeof(StNode));
    newNode->value = value;
    
    //[both]=value of previous node pointer if it is last node
    newNode->both = (long)lastNode; 
    
    //calculating previous node [both] value
    lastNode->both = (long)newNode ^ lastNode->both;
    
    return newNode;
}

pStNode get(pStNode headNode, int index)
{    
    pStNode prevNode;
    pStNode currNode;
    long tmp;
    
    //special handling
    //case: cur=1, prev=0
    //we have set previous node of head node value to be 0 manually
    currNode = (StNode *) ((headNode->both) ^ 0);
    prevNode = headNode;
    
    //skim through linked list
    for(int i=2; i<=index; i++)
    {
        tmp = (long)prevNode;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = (StNode *)(currNode->both ^ tmp);
    }
    
    return currNode;
}


int main() {  
    
    //I named first node as headNode, and last node as tailNode
    //create head node with both=0 since there is no previous node to it
    pStNode headNode = (StNode *) malloc(sizeof(StNode));
    headNode->both = 0; 
    headNode->value = 2;
    
    //assign pointers
    pStNode tailNode = headNode;
    
    //lets add 10 nodes after head, and assign values
    for(int i=3; i<13; i++)
    {
        tailNode = add(tailNode, i);
    }
    
    //get node value where index=3
    pStNode iNode = get(headNode, 3);
    printf( "result: %d\n",  iNode->value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`long` isn't necessarily a good choice of integer type for storing pointers - luckily `<stdint.h>` provides us with `uintptr_t` which is guaranteed to be wide enough for this purpose (always prefer an unsigned type when working with bitwise operations).

I dislike hiding pointer types behind typedefs such as `pStNode`.  I think it's clearer to use the pointer type directly - or a pointer to `const StNode` where appropriate.  For example, `get()` should take a pointer to const.

It's unnecessary (and generally considered unwise) to cast the result of `malloc()`.  `void*` can be assigned to any kind of pointer in C.

There's quite a lot missing from the code that I would expect from something claiming to be an *implementation* of the list.  There's no function for removing elements, and the only accessor provided is the poorly-performing random-access getter.

In particular, you haven't provided `next()` and `prev()` functions, which I'd expect to see if you want to demonstrate that both directions of traversal work correctly.

Why does `get()` accept a signed integer for the index?  It appears that negative values are all equivalent to 0; we should either make those work or accept an unsigned type instead.  Also, we can safely reduce the scope of `tmp` to within the loop.

It's best to write `main()` as a function prototype `int main(void)` (i.e. taking no arguments, rather than an unspecified number of arguments).  And unlike other functions, `main()` doesn't need to return a value for success, so that line can be omitted.

Comment: In my opinion, it will be impossible to implement next(), and prev() functions unless current and previous or next node pointers are referenced as a parameter. I think that is why the original question asked to extract Nth element (assuming swiping down from head node). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: about the rest, I will implement new method according to your suggestion also

Comment: Please take a look at new version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251932/xor-linked-list-implementation-follow-up

Answer (score 8):

```
long both;
```

1. Using a `long` for storing a cast pointer can be both wasteful and too little. Just use the dedicated [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). Even if your implementation might not be fully up to C99 (MS greets), it probably has `<stdint.h>` and the typedef.

```
pStNode newNode = (StNode *) malloc(sizeof(StNode));
```

The above line demonstrates three bad ideas:

2. More pieces to keep track of means more complexity, which is bad. Thus hiding pointers behind typedefs is a bad idea, unless that pointer-type is never dereferenced, and is thus the one true type used.
3. Casting a `void*` is superfluous and error-prone.
   See "*[Do I cast the result of malloc?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)*
   ".
4. Don't use `sizeof(TYPE)` unless unavoidable. Getting it right even if the types aren't obscured is error-prone. Just use `sizeof *pointer`.

```
pStNode get(pStNode headNode, int index)
```

5. There is a type uniquely suited as an index: `size_t`. Alternatively, if you want something signed, you might be interested in `ptrdiff_t`. Though yes, if your use-case guarantees few enough nodes, `int` might work.
6. You really should encapsulate your list somehow. Currently, you are creating a one-off in `main()`.
   Also, cleanup should be possible without terminating the program.
7. If you use at least C99, `main()` has an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: Please check my new version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251932/xor-linked-list-implementation-follow-up