# XOR linked list implementation - Follow Up

Tags: c, linked-list

This question is a follow up question to the [XOR linked list implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251894/xor-linked-list-implementation).

I am posting a new code here with taking into consideration the suggestions of Toby Speight and Deduplicator. Please advise how the code efficiency can be improved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct StNode {
    int value;
    uintptr_t both;
}; 
typedef struct StNode StHexNode;

StHexNode *add(StHexNode *lastNode, int value)
{
    StHexNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct StNode));
    newNode->value = value;
    
    //latest node's [both]=pointer value pointing previous node:
    newNode->both = (uintptr_t)lastNode; 
    //calculating previous node [both]:
    lastNode->both = (uintptr_t)newNode ^ lastNode->both;
    return newNode;
}

StHexNode *get(StHexNode *headNode, unsigned int index)
{
    
    StHexNode *prevNode;
    StHexNode *currNode;
    uintptr_t tmp;
    
    //cur=1, prev=0
    currNode = (struct StNode *) ((headNode->both) ^ 0);
    prevNode = headNode;
    
    for(int i=2; i<=index; i++)
    {
        tmp = (uintptr_t)prevNode;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = (struct StNode *) (currNode->both ^ tmp);
    }
    return currNode;
}

int free_list(StHexNode *headNode)
{
    StHexNode *prevNode;
    StHexNode *currNode;
    uintptr_t tmp;
    int ctr=0;
    
    //case: there is a only head node in the list
    if(headNode->both == 0) 
    {
        free(headNode);
        return ++ctr;
    }
    
    //prev=head, curr=second_node
    currNode = (struct StNode *) ((headNode->both) ^ 0);
    prevNode = headNode;
    
    while(currNode->both != (uintptr_t)prevNode)
    {
        tmp = (uintptr_t)prevNode;
        free(prevNode);
        ctr++;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = (struct StNode *) (currNode->both ^ tmp);
    }
    //last node
    free(currNode);
    ctr++;
    
    return ctr;
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int i;
    
    //I named first node as headNode, and last node as tailNode
    //create head node with both=0 since there is no previous node to it
    StHexNode *headNode = malloc(sizeof(struct StNode));
    StHexNode *tailNode = headNode; //last node pointer in the list
    
    //lets add 100 nodes after head
    //special handling of both value at head node
    for(headNode->both = 0, i=100; i<200; i++)
    {
        tailNode = add(tailNode, i);
        //printf("last node value:%d\n", tailNode->value);
    }


     //get index=50 node value
     StHexNode *iNode = get(headNode, 50);
     printf( "result: %d\n",  iNode->value);

     //free memory
     printf("we released %d list\n", free_list(headNode));
       
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't take Deduplicator's advice to use `sizeof *newNode` as argument to `malloc()`?

Comment: I still see no function to release the resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use a different name for a `struct` and its `typedef`

Why is `struct StNode` typedef'ed to `StHexNode`? What does the `Hex` mean here, I don't see anything hexadecimal or hexagonal in the rest of the code? You can use exactly the same name for a `struct` as for its `typedef`, so I would just use that:

```
typedef struct StNode StNode;
```

You can also combine the `typedef` with the `struct` definition:

```
typedef struct StNode {
    ...
} StNode;
```

## Use `typedef`s consistently

I see you use `StHexNode` in some places, and `struct StNode` in others. Be consistent and only use the typedef'ed variant.

## Avoid repeating type names if possible

In this line:

```
StHexNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct StNode));
```

Besides the inconstent use of the typedef, you repeat the type twice. That makes this error prone (if you make a mistake on the right side it will compile without errors but it will probably be wrong), and if you ever have to change the type of the variable `newNode`, you would have to do it in at least two places. It is better to avoid repeating the type name, but instead repeat the variable name:

```
StNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

## Prefer using compound assignment operators to avoid repetition

Use [compound assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment) if possible to save some typing, and also avoiding possible mistakes. For example, instead of:

```
lastNode->both = (uintptr_t)newNode ^ lastNode->both;
```

Prefer:

```
lastNode->both ^= (uintptr_t)newNode;
```

## Simplifying `get()`

You can simplify the function `get()` somewhat. In particular, when looping over the elements of a list, try to start at index `0`, and avoid making the start and end special cases. You can do this here like so:

```
StNode *get(StNode *headNode, unsigned int index)
{   
    StNode *currNode = headNode;
    uintptr_t prev = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        uintptr_t next = currNode->both ^ prev;
        prev = (uintptr_t)currNode;
        currNode = (StNode *)(next);
    }

    return currNode;
}
```

Note that you could even avoid the declaration of `currNode` if you change the name of `headNode` to `currNode`, but I would personally keep it as it is above, as it makes the role of the parameter and the local variable more clear.

## Simplifying `free_list()`

The same goes for `free_list()`: you should not need to make a list of one element a special case. Also, why is `free_list()` calculating the number of elements of a list that will have been deleted by the time it returns?

```
void free_list(StNode *headNode)
{
    StNode *currNode = headNode;
    uintptr_t prev = 0;
    
    while (currNode)
    {
        uintptr_t next = currNode->both ^ prev;
        prev = (uintptr_t)currNode;
        free(currNode);
        currNode = (StNode *)(next);
    }
}
```

## Use a unique and consistent naming scheme

If you want to use your XOR linked list in a real program, consider that names like `StNode` and `get()` are very generic and will likely conflict with other parts of a larger project. Maybe you need a binary tree implementation as well for example, and how are you going to name its function to retrieve an element at a given index? To solve this issue in C, come up with a unique prefix that you can use for all the struct and function names. For example, prefix everything with `xllist_`:

```
typedef struct xllist_node {
    ...
} xllist_node;

xllist_node *xllist_add(xllist_node *lastNode, int value);
xllist_node *xllist_get(xllist_node *headNode, usigned int index);
void xllist_free(xllist_node *headNode);
```

Of course you can argue about what the prefix should be exactly. I find something like `xor_linked_list` or `XorLinkedList` a bit too verbose, so `xllist` is a compromise: it still has `list` clearly in the name, and if you don't know what `xl` is you can look it up, and once you have seen what it means it is easy to remember that `xl` stands for `XOR linked` I hope.

## Create a `struct` representing the whole list

You have a `struct` for a node, but not one for the whole list. That means the caller of your functions has to manually allocate the first list element, and it needs to keep track of both the head and tail node. It is much better if you create a `struct` representing the list:

```
typedef struct xllist {
    xllist_node *head;
    xllist_node *tail;
} xllist;
```

And then pass a pointer to this `struct` to functions like `xllist_get()`, `xllist_add()` and `xllist_free()`, like so:

```
xllist_node *xllist_add(xllist *list, int value) {
    xllist_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    newNode->both = (uintptr_t)xllist->tail;
    newNode->value = value;

    if (xllist->tail) {
        // Append it to the existing tail node
        xllist->tail->both ^= (uintptr_t)newNode;
        xllist->tail = newNode;
    } else {
        // The list was empty
        xllist->head = newNode;
        xllist->tail = newNode;
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

And you use it like so in `main()`:

```
xllist myList = {NULL, NULL}; // declare an empty list

for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
{
    xllist_add(&myList, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated version after applying advice from G. Sliepen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct StNode {
    int value;
    uintptr_t both;
} StNode; 

//keep track of linked list head and tail
typedef struct xllist {
    //I named first node as headNode, and last node as tailNode
    StNode *head;
    StNode *tail;
} xllist;

StNode *xllist_add(xllist *list, int value)
{
    StNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);  
    newNode->value = value;
    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        //very first node
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
        list->head->both = 0;
        return newNode;
    }
    
    list->tail->both ^= (uintptr_t)newNode;
    newNode->both = (uintptr_t)list->tail;
    list->tail = newNode;
    
    return newNode;
}

StNode *xllist_get(xllist *list, unsigned int index)
{   
    StNode *currNode = list->head;
    uintptr_t prev=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
    {
        uintptr_t next = currNode->both ^ prev;
        prev = (uintptr_t)currNode;
        currNode = (StNode *)next;
    }
    return currNode;
}

void xllist_free(xllist *list)
{
    StNode *currNode=list->head;
    uintptr_t prev=0, next;
    
    while(currNode)
    {
        next = prev ^ (uintptr_t)currNode->both;
        prev = (uintptr_t)currNode;
        free(currNode);
        currNode = (StNode *)next;
        
    }
    
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int i; 
    xllist myList = {NULL, NULL};
    
    //lets xllist_add 100 nodes after head
    //special handling of both value at head node
    for(i=100; i<200; i++)
    {
        xllist_add(&myList, i);
    }
    
    //xllist_get index=50 node value
    StNode *iNode = xllist_get(&myList, 50);
    printf( "result: %d\n",  iNode->value);
    
    //free memory
    xllist_free(&myList);
   
}
```

Comment: I would still rename `StNode` to `xllist_node`, again to have a consistent prefix and to avoid possible conflicts with other data structures that have nodes.

Comment: got it. Important thing is I got the concept. will very appreciated if you review my codes in the future.

Comment: Sure, just post new questions here on CodeReview and I and others will have a look at it :)